# BIOS taking a long time to load and computer switching off

Tags: bios, hardware-failure

I did use Ubuntu for my simulations which I kept running for a month. Towards the end my PC started showing some problems in functioning. My simulations were running on graphic card and 3/4 cores in CPU.

Now the problem is something like this. My PC takes a long time to get to BIOS, about a minute after I switch on the power and the OS is very unstable. Sometimes USB faulter some time after OS is loaded and after I recently installed Fedora, it switches off after a minute or 2, almost every time.

What's the possible solution to this? I'm pretty sure it's hardware or BIOS related. Thanks

Hardware:
GA-AX370-Gaming(rev1)
Zotax GTX1060
Corsair Vengeance RAM
Ryzen 3 2200G processor
Kingston SSD

Comment: Check if any of the components aren't overheating (CPU, GPU, MB), all fans are spining and temperature readings in BIOS are ok. Then I would try to unplug everything that you can (disks, usb devices, card readers, etc..) from MB, leave just monitor and keyboard and check if it's taking the same amout of time to get to BIOS. Post more information about hardware.

Comment: Complications have developed. I was updating bios and at 63%, computer just freezed. After sufficient time passage, I pressed reset button and I've not been able to get to my backup bios (dualBIOS)

Comment: Well, that's a solution too, claim warranty :)

Comment: It has also been super unstable throughout the year, maybe this is the best! A fantastic solution :D